# Date format displayed is not the desirable outcome despite code seems to be working in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created this so every time I change the priority, the target date changes dynamically by adding the number of days of the priority selected to the date the ticket created. However, the result and format on the screen(Target date box) is not clear. Any help about this?

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetTargetDate(int? PriorityID)
    {
        DateTime datenow = DateTime.Now;
        Priority priority = new Priority();
        TicketViewModel ticket = new TicketViewModel();
        priority = priorityService.Get(PriorityID.Value);

        ticket.TargetDate = datenow.AddDays(priority.No_Of_Days);

        return Json(ticket.TargetDate, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

VIEW CODE(JQUERY)

```js
<script>

  function getTargetdate() {

  var company = $('#Priority_Code').val();
   if (company != null) {
    $.ajax({
     url: '@Url.Action("GetTargetDate", "Ticket")',
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'JSON',
     //This is query string i.e.country_id = 123
     data: { PriorityID: company },
     success: function (targetdate) {
      $("#TargetDate").val(targetdate);
     },
     error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(errorThrown);
     }
    });
   }
  else {
   $('#TargetDate').empty(); // clear the current elements in select box
  };
 } 


</script>
```

DROPDOWN LIST CODE

```html
<div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Priority_Code, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
      <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Priority_Code, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Priority_Code, new SelectList(Model.Priorities, "Id", "Description", Model.Priority_Code), new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "getTargetdate()" })
      </div>
     </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXYKy.jpg)